# Very strange bug in Ubuntu (introduced in recent months' updates)

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers, thinkpad

I have been using my ThinkPad x200 with Ubuntu since I bought it several yeas ago, every time doing a clean install when switching versions instead of upgrading one on top of the other.

I have never had any issue with the hardware drivers, and Ubuntu, as usual, was quite pleasing.

However, few months ago (I do not recall when exactly that happened, perhaps during May or June this year) I have noticed that when I boot the system, the WiFi is not available, that is:

- Hardware button is set to active
- On top-right corner I see the BT icon, but not the WiFi icon
- ifconfig / ip addr show the interface wlan0 is down

Bringing it up with `ifconfig wlan0 up` make no change.
Plugging in a cable, "wakes up" networking and WiFi icon becomes available, as well as active and UP interface.

I wonder which logs shall I look at in order to start understanding the roots of this issue?

I could not grasp anything out of `/var/log/syslog` that will explain this.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 3):

This occurred to me also.

If you turn off the wifi and reboot then this problem occurs.  The `enable wireless` get unchecked.

Use `rfkill unblock all`  in such case to enable Wi-fi.

*For me, this is better than pressing hardware button twice to bring up the wi-fi, as it was earlier.*

Comment: in my case, neither pressing hardware button twice don't work, nor the `rfkill unblock all` you have suggested.

Comment: what is the output of `rfkill list all` in that state

Comment: see my pate at https://gist.github.com/3163266